# Is there Special Paging mode in XP for high memory usage scenarios

Tags: windows-xp, paging, commit-charge

I have observed that once my PC (WinXP-x86) has a Peak Commit Charge exceeding the Total Physical Memory (as reported by Task Manager) that my PC grinds to a halt.

Obviously paging is going to be the cause of this, but the strange thing is that it doesn't seem to recover properly once I have brought the memory usage back down.  It has always seemed to me that Windows goes into a special aggressive paging mode, and that the only way to get it back to normal is to reboot.

Is this all in my imagination, or does Windows really behave like this?  If it is real, how do I get it to go back to normal without rebooting?

Comment: I've never heard of this **special aggressive** paging mode.  If anything, the memory manager under XP. . .